# AndroidAnnotations. button click inside actionLayout of menuItem

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-menu, android-annotations

In AA+AppCompat, I try to change below code in Activity to AA-style.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_done, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.itemDone);
    View menuView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    mButtonQuestionPost = (Button) menuView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMenuDone);
    mButtonQuestionPost.setOnClickListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

First, changed head of **Activity** as below. The menu was shown as expected.

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_question_post)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.menu_done)
public class QuestionPostActivity extends FragmentActivity {...
```

And, try to do button click method as below but nothing fired. I changed `@Click` with `@OptionsItem` or changed attributes this and that but no luck.

```
@Click(R.id.buttonMenuDone)
void buttonMenuDone(){
    if (mQuestionPostFragment.validatePost()) {
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
        mQuestionPostFragment.postQuestion();
    }
}
```

**menu.xml** is as below. Note that I'm using `actionLayout` for design purpose.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemDone"
    android:title="@string/done"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/item_menu_done"
    />
```

**item_menu_done** is as below.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMenuDone"
    android:text="@string/done"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    />
```

The AA-generated file does not have `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem)`, but hardly to make it with AA. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot bind a listener with `@Click` to a menu action view, since `Activity.findViewById` cannot find that view inside the menu items. What you can do is injecting the menuitem, then, manually bind your listener as you already did.

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_question_post)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.menu_done)
public class QuestionPostActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @OptionsMenuItem(R.id.menuItemDone)
    MenuItem buttonMenuDone;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // this will be called by the generated subclass after it injected the menu
        MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemDone).findViewById(R.id.buttonMenuDone).setOnClickListener(this);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. So we cannot remove `implements View.OnClickListener` in this scenario.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Of course you can create an inner class or anonymous class so you do not have to implement that interface with your `Activity` if yo do not want to.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs it, nowadays you can use the OptionsItem() annotation like so:

```
//Even with system items
@OptionsItem(android.R.id.home)
void onHomeItemClicked() {
    finish();
}

//Or your custom ones
@OptionsItem(R.id.buttonMenuDone)
void onMenuDoneItemClicked() {
    //Do your stuff
}
```